# Can this circulant determinant be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The question is:

If $a,b,c$ are negative distinct real numbers,then the determinant $$ \begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
b & c & a\\ 
c & a & b
\end{vmatrix} $$ is $$(a) \le 0 \quad (b) \gt 0 \quad (c) \lt 0 \quad (d) \ge 0 $$

My strategy: I identifed that the matrix is a circulant hence the determinant can be expressed in the form of $-(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc)$ which implies that $-(a+b+c)\frac{1}{2}[(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2]$ hence $(-)(-)(+) \gt 0$ but the answers says it is $\ge 0$, so can we have three $a,b,c$ such that the answer is $0$ ?

Comment: What happens if a=b=c?

Comment: @Martin:The questions says that $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct negative numbers,so can a=b=c ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the question more carefully.

Comment: @Martin:It's alright,happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you require $a, b, c$ distinct, no.  The term $a+b+c$ can't be $0$ as they are all the same sign and the other term is a sum of squares which can only be $0$ if $a=b=c$.

Comment: Exactly, so the correct answer should be (b) right?

Comment: I agree with you.  Maybe the author forgot about "distinct".

Answer (score 4):

Consider the equation:

$$(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)/3 = abc$$

as expressing the equality of the arithmetic and geometric means of $a^3,b^3,c^3$.  By [a well known result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) this is only possible if the three cubes are equal.  So, no, we cannot get them distinct and have the determinant be zero.

Comment: I knew this result but it never really occur to me till now to use it here,thanks and +1 :-)

Comment: @Debanjan: Yes, just going a different route!  Your solution (embedded in the question) already shows that something less than all three distinct suffices to give a nonzero result, i.e. all three must be equal to reach zero.