# Prove that there are infinitely many triples

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many triples $(a,b,c)$ of integers such that $9a^3+4b^3-48c^3+36abc=1$.

It's similar to this one: [USATST 2012](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h550608p3195789). I actually aim to do the following:
from a solution $(a,b,c)$ be able to generate one more. For the links problem, if $(a,b,c)$ works then $(a+2b+2c,a+b+2c,a+b+c)$ does so. Can this be applied here?

Comment: For the method you refer to, first you need one triple. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes, that is (1,1,1)

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: I don't know. I suppose it is from a math competition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$ \left|\begin{matrix}\sqrt[3]{9}a & \sqrt[3]{4}b & \sqrt[3]{-48}c\\ \sqrt[3]{-48}c & \sqrt[3]{9}a & \sqrt[3]{4}b\\ \sqrt[3]{4}b & \sqrt[3]{-48}c & \sqrt[3]{9}a \end{matrix}\right| = 9a^3 + 4b^3 - 48c^3 + 36abc$

Comment: You can construct similar matrix with $d_1a^3+d_2b^3+d_3c^3-3\sqrt[3]{d_1d_2d_3}abc$.

Comment: And how is this supposed to give infinite triples? I would like to see a solution using what I described above. Thanks!

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: Try it yourself - just substitute LHS with $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ and take powers. For example, take the matrix to the fourth power and you get $(-215,-80,-158)$. Then you can relate the coefficients.

Comment: Aargh I tried but can't get the desired result ... can you provide a full solution please? Actually what I need is the ''generator formula'' ...

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: @math_here you need to take the illustrated matrix, integer variables a,b,c. Then write another one next to it, say variables u,v,w. Multiply the two matrices together and confirm that the product is a matrix of the same pattern, involving new integer coefficients, call them x,y,z.  There will be explicit recipes, x will be an explicit (and very clean) function of a,b,c,u,v,w. Same for y,z. If you don't know how to multiply matrices....

Comment: @math_here In case you didn't know there is a [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) for the determinant of a ciculant matrix (this $3$-dim case is mentioned e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32305/242))

Comment: @WillJagy (an Gone) Thank you very much!